# Merge different string in one

Tags: c, string, merge, char

I have this code:

```
int main(){

    char buf[40];
    char buff[40];
    char bufff[40];

    fgets(buf, 40, stdin);  
    fgets(buff, 40, stdin);
    fgets(bufff, 40, stdin);
}
```

input:

```
Hello 
from 
Earth
```

I must have this output:

```
Hello
from
Earth
Hello from Earth
```

I send the code to a valutation platform, and it returned to me that with the following code I'll get wrong output:

```
buf[strlen(buf)-1] = "";
buff[strlen(buff)-1] = "";
bufff[strlen(bufff)-1] = "";    

printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", buf, buff, bufff);
printf("%s %s %s", buf, buff, bufff);
```

Comment: @user3121023 That is correct, put it as answer

Comment: the `fgets()` function always NUL terminates the string so no need to perform that step separately.  And `strlen()` will not work if the string is not already NUL terminated.  However, the `fgets()` will also include the trailing newline, which you will want to eliminate, perhaps with something like: `char * newline; if( strchar( buf, '\n' ) ) { *newline = '\0'; }`  Note: do not assume there is a newline, always check first.

Comment: in the assignment statements, like this one: `buff[strlen(buff)-1] = "";`   The `""` resolves to a pointer to a string.  Assigning a pointer to a string to a char will not work.   use this kind of line instead: `buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';`

Comment: @user3629249 Consider that `buff[0]` may equal `'\0'`.  What would `buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0'` do?  `buff[strcspn(buff,"\n")]=0;` is a simple alternative.

Comment: @chux, other than a 0 has a hex value of 0x00000000 in a 32 bit architecture which will not really fit into a single byte.   However, if depending on the implicit conversion feature of the compiler, then your code would work,  my Comment about `fgets()` covered that detail.  My comment about the assignment of `buff[] = ""` was about trying to assign an address into a char array.  I do not see the problem to which your referring.

Comment: @user3629249  `fgets()` reads until encountering `'\n'`.  If it first reads a null character, it saves that in `buff[0]` and continues reading until a newline is read.  Your comment attempts `buff[strlen(buff)-1]` which results in `buff[SIZE_MAX]`, as `strlen(buff)` is then `(size_t) 0`.   `buff[SIZE_MAX]` is certainly outside `buff[]` range and is UB.  Entering a null character is a potential hacker exploit - code should not get fooled.  An issue for robust code.

Answer (score 2):

- `""` is a string literal, which is an array, and it will be converted to integer in implementation-defined manner. You should use `'\0'` as NUL character.
- The last characters of lines need not be newline characters.
- You will have to remove the spaces in the input to match the output.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    /* initialize to avoid undefined behavior when no data is read */
    char buf[40] = "";
    char buff[40] = "";
    char bufff[40] = "";
    char *lf;

    /* read the input */
    fgets(buf, 40, stdin);
    fgets(buff, 40, stdin);
    fgets(bufff, 40, stdin);

    /* remove newline characters if they exists */
    if ((lf = strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
    if ((lf = strchr(buff, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
    if ((lf = strchr(bufff, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';

    /* remove space characters: implement here to match the actual specification */
    if ((lf = strchr(buf, ' ')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
    if ((lf = strchr(buff, ' ')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
    if ((lf = strchr(bufff, ' ')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';

    /* print */
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", buf, buff, bufff);
    printf("%s %s %s", buf, buff, bufff);

    return 0;
}
```

Omitted in this code, you should check if readings are successful.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this simple function for removing right-trailing whitespace in general. Should also remove additional spaces. And you can even adapt it easily to filter out other symbols you want.

```
#define IS_WHITESPACE(Char) (Char == ' ' || Char == '\n' || Char == '\t')

void trim_right(char *string)
{
    int i;

    for (i = strlen(string) - 1; i >= 0; i++)
         if (IS_WHITESPACE(string[i]))
             string[i] = '\0';
         else
             break;
}
```

Comment: leaving out the braces makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  And any editing is almost sure to result in the code not working properly.  Strongly suggest always wrap the `for` `if` `else` code blocks with braces.